# The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

Tags: r, xgboost

I don't know why I'm getting this error! My data `training` is a sparse matrix.

```
dim(training)
> 14407 161

dim(label.train)
> 14407 1

xgb.train <- xgb.DMatrix(data = training, label = label.train)
> Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) : 
The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data
```

I have checked my data and:

- `label.train` is a data.frame
- `training` does not have all zero rows or columns
- all values in `training` are numeric

PS. My data is huge so I can't post a reproducible code, just need tips for what might be wrong from those who have experienced this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're getting the error because your labels are a data.frame.  Passing them as a vector or a matrix works for me.

```
vec_y <- mtcars$vs
mat_y <- as.matrix(mtcars$vs)
df_y  <- mtcars[,8,drop=FALSE] #column vs is the 8th column

x <- as.matrix(mtcars[,-8])    #column vs is the 8th column

#vector labels: works
xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data=x, label=vec_y)
#matrix labels: works
xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data=x, label=mat_y)
#df labels: doesnt work
xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data=x, label=df_y)
```

Comment: Wow, you just saved me from killing myself over this!

What was driving me insane is that I had the same code in a different script where it worked with no problems. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely your other script's data did not have any missing (NA) value. When you sparse (I'm guessing you were trying to one hot encoding columns) a data frame to a matrix, R will automatically remove missing value and hence the error.

The best practice is to use "is.na" to replace all nulls to 0.